# Codecademy jQuery stuck on "Modifying HTML Elements"

Tags: javascript, jquery

We're making a To-do list

Here is the instructions:

> Perfect! Now we want to add our HTML element to the document. We can do this using our handy .append() function.
>   Let's go ahead and append to our div with the .list class. We'll append a  with class="item", since we'll want a way to target our appended s later when we remove them. (A "to do" list is no good if we can't check things off it.)
>   We'll want the contents of our div to be the contents of our input field, which we saved in the variable toAdd. That means when we append, we'll want to append:

```
'<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>'
```

> Go ahead and .append() a  with class="item" to the .list div of your HTML document, then MAKE SURE to click your button to add an item—the exercise will wait for you to do so!

I can't understand what needs to be done.

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function () {
   var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
   $(".list").append("div class='item'" + toAdd + "div");
});});
```

But it doesn't work when I type anything and click the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close! Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
       var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
       $(".list").append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
    });
});
```

You didn't have the HTML angle brackets inside your append(). Also, the `$("button")` should be `$("#button")` as it is ID "button", not a real `<button>`.

Comment: Still when I type something and click "Add" nothing happens.

and Codecademy says "Oops, try again. It looks like you didn't append a new <div> to your .list."

http://i.imgur.com/2LEs6LD.jpg

Comment: Can you paste the HTML for your list div please?

Comment: Codecademy made the HTML for me I'm only writing the script..

Here it is anyway:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>To Do</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>To Do</h2>
  <form name="checkListForm">
   <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
  </form>
  <div id="button">Add!</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="list"></div>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: Change button to #button

Comment: That's it!

How foolish of me. :D

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".list").append("div class='item'" + toAdd + "div");
```

should instead be:

```
$(".list").append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
```

or

```
$(".list").append($('<div>').addClass('item').text(toAdd));
```